# knockout.js text change depends on counter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and I like to have a text change value depends on a counter. Can it be done using observable or I need to do a subscription ?
I am doing udacity js design pattern course and it has not cover subscription
but when I google for similar solution of this it uses subscription
thanks for all the help!

```
    <h3 data-bind="text: catLevel"></h2>
    <div data-bind="text: clickCount"></div>

this.incrementCounter = function(){
    this.clickCount(this.clickCount()+1);
    //if (this.ClickCount > 10){
    //this.catLevel='Infant';
    //}

      this.catLevel = ko.computed(function() {
        if(this.clickCount>10){
          return "Infant";
        }else{

          return "Newborn";
        }
    //return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/launeric/b3929xcr/#&togetherjs=GkChVL86zO

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't put your computed definition inside your increment function. You're redefining the computed every time the function runs, which defeats the purpose of a computed.

Remember that to get the value from `clickCount`, you need to invoke it (an observable is a function). So your code should look like this:

```
  this.catLevel = ko.computed(function () {
    if (this.clickCount() > 10) {
      return "Infant";
    } else {
      return "Newborn";
    }
  }, this);

  this.incrementCounter = function () {
    this.clickCount(this.clickCount() + 1);
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var viewModel = function() {
  this.name = ko.observable('Tabby');
  this.clickCount = ko.observable(0);
  this.catLevel = ko.observable('Newborn');
  this.imgSrc = ko.observable('https://static.pexels.com/photos/33358/cat-fold-view-grey-fur.jpg');
  this.imageAttribution = ko.observable('https://www.flickr.com/photos/onesharp/9648464288');
  this.incrementCounter = function() {
    this.clickCount(this.clickCount() + 1);
    if (this.clickCount() > 10) {
      console.log("brabra");
      this.catLevel("inFant");
    }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsbin.com/tiyijer/edit?html,css,js,console,output